# Ruby on Rails: 'show' route of account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

Currently I have two models, `Account` and `User`. Account has many users, and users belongs to account. I want to show account page but keep getting `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts"}, missing required keys: [:id]` error.

`Accounts` controller

```
def show
   @account = Account.find_by(params[:id])
end
```

Links to account page

```
<%= link_to "Account Settings", account_path %>
```

Routes

```
resources :accounts, only: [:new, :create, :show, :edit, :update]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here:

```
<%= link_to "Account Settings", account_path %>
```

Rails said 'missing required keys: [:id]' that means that you must send id to show the method

```
<%= link_to "Account Settings", account_path(123) %>
```

after when somebody will click on your link, the controller will take this id here:

```
@account = Account.find_by(params[:id])
```

will find your record into DB, and redirect you to :show page

Comment: I modified the link to `<%= link_to "Account Settings", account_path(@current_user.account_id) %>`, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Account Settings", account_path(@current_user.account_id) %>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.